# Flutter app dose not set/get shared preferences value in ios after 16.3

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I am having a strange problem with my app after iOS 16.3 version, For some reason, some of the shared preferences do not set/get values in that version, which causes them to have null values. I do not get any errors when setting values; this only happens when the app is in the app store. During debugging,  everything works as it should.
Does anyone else have this problem or a solution?

I tried different solutions but nothing worked so far

Comment: Hey, all you have to do is verify your code into MaterialApp before calling any methods; if any methods call for storing data, they will transfer to the spalach screen or home screen.
good, it serves my purpose.

Comment: thanks, so why my code was working before the iOS 16.3.1 version, and why only this happens to some shared preferences? 4-5 shared-preferences can set value without any problem and the rest does not